# How do you get /me/feed using PHP SDK v4

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the latest version of the Facebook PHP SDK v4.0.12.  I'm trying to grab my feed using the SDK.  I have the SDK setup and working properly.

I started with this example code:

```
// save the session
$_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();

// create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
$session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

// graph api request for user data
$request = (new FacebookRequest( 
  $session, 
  'GET', 
  '/me' 
))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

var_dump($request);
```

All of that works great, i can see my name, age, gender, etc.  No problems with that request.

I think i should be able to get my /me/feed using this same code with one subtle change.

```
// save the session
$_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();

// create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
$session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

// graph api request for user data
$request = (new FacebookRequest( 
  $session, 
  'GET', 
  '/me/feed' 
))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

var_dump($request);
```

But, unfortunately, this does not work.  I get an empty array or as others have stated on here they see "object(Facebook\GraphUser)#334 (1) { ["backingData":protected]=> array(0) { } }".  The similar questions i had found didnt quite answer it for me.  I've tried a few things, but not having much luck.

**Update #2 - Reply to the comment below**

My login link looks like this:

```
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'user_status,read_stream' ) ) 
. '" target="_top">Login</a>';
```

I've tried logging out and then logging back in to hopefully reset the permissions.

I also tried this:

```
// graph api request for user data
$request = (new FacebookRequest( 
  $session, 
        'GET', 
        '/me/feed' 
))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

This outputs a blank array.

Comment: what "few things" did you try? did you try checking out that access token to see if read_stream is authorized correctly?

Comment: you are onto somethere there.  I did not check the access token.  I just did just now and i see the permissions are wrong. "public_profile, basic_info, email, user_friends" - so how do i reset the access token with the proper permissions?

Comment: ok, I'm all set now.  Thank you!  That was exactly it.  I cleared my access token and logged out and logged in.  I got the pop-up window again and the correct permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i´ve answered it in the comments only, here´s the real one:

You need to make sure that `read_stream` is authorized correctly, by checking out the Access Token in the [debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Btw, read this before creating any App with read_stream: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream