# Use php sdk v4 to get 3 or more wall posts to display on website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Please I need a working example of a php script, that makes use of the [php sdk v4 for facebook](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4), to pull the most recent wall posts from a user's page.

I've looked around in google and on stackoverflow but most of the examples just show me how to get a login through fb script(which I already have set up on the site I am working on). I did find this [php sdk v4 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27237575/how-do-you-get-me-feed-using-php-sdk-v4), but it left out how to get the access token(also if you can please include how to get an access token that doesn't expire in 60 days). I just started using the sdk today and have no idea how to get started. I have this bit of code which I got from copying and pasting from some of the examples online, but I don't know what to add so that I can get the feed/posts as explained in the linked question.

```
<?php    
require_once('facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php');

session_start();

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('xxxxxxxx','xxxxxxxxx');
```

I may be asking for too much, or my question might be to general, but I really just need the example. If asking for the code is too much, please link me to an example online that shows me how to do it. I've also looked at the fb docs but they are very confusing for someone who has never used the sdk before. Thank you, in advance,for any and all help!

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution, here is the breakdown and my resources that helped me achieve what I wanted.

Step 0:

create a fb app as a developer and get the app Id and app Secret.

Step 1:

Use this link to see how to set up a basic interaction with fb and to create a GET request. [Basic FB interaction](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/)

Step 2:

If you want to hit a specific fb page or your own page use this link to find out how to get the page id. [Page Id](http://tomrobertshaw.net/2013/01/get-the-latest-post-of-a-facebook-page/)

Step 3:

Then if you want to get the posts like I wanted change the code in the last if at the bottom of the first link from this:

```
if ( isset( $session ) ) {
// save the session
$_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
// create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
$session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );
// graph api request for user data
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
$response = $request->execute();
// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
// print profile data
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
// print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'http://yourwebsite.com/app/logout.php' ) . '">Logout</a>';
}
```

to this

```
// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) { 
// save the session
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
// create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );
// graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/'.$pageId.'/posts?limit=3' );
  $response = $request->execute();
// get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
// print profile data
  echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
}
```

Step 4(optional):

Finally, you may get an error or a bug that your $session variable is NULL, if you are using the FacebookRedirectLoginHelper function to redirect to the same page you are currently on, see the code inside the last else of this link. [NULL session variable, redirect to current page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526621/why-is-getsessionfromredirect-return-a-null)

Comment: PS It may or may not change anything, but I also, under the settings tab in the advanced options(top left), changed " Native or Desktop app "  from No to Yes